# Use dropdown select value as api param is throwing name variable not defined error

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-redux

I am trying to use dropdown current selected value I have defined it as "name" variable here to pass to api as query param. I am getting name is not defined here. The api call has to change dynamically based on the dropdown value

```
 axios.get('/api/search/a', {
                params: {
                     name: {name}
                }
            }
```

Full Code:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
    import {Box} from "@material-ui/core";
    
    class test extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data : [],
                isLoading: true,
                name:""
            };
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('/api/search/a', {
                params: {
                     name: {name}
                }
            }
                ).then(response => response.data)
                .then(responsePayload => {
                    var dts = [];
                    var xds = [];
                    var yds = [];
    
                    for (var index = 0; index < responsePayload.length; index++) {
                        var dt = responsePayload[index].timestamp;
                        var dts = new Date(dt);
                        var shortMonthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "short" }).format;
                        var shortName = shortMonthName(date);
                        var day = dt.substring(8,10);
                        dts.push(shortName + " " + day);
                        xds.push(responsePayload[index].gg);
                        yds.push(responsePayload[index].kk);
                      }
    
                    this.setState({
                                      data: {
                                          labels: dts,
                                          datasets: [
                                              {
                                                  label: 'XXX',
                                                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(154,205,50,0.8)',
                                                  borderColor: 'rgba(154,205,50,1)',
                                                  borderWidth: 1,
                                                  hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(154,205,50,0.5)',
                                                  hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(154,205,50,0.8)',
                                                  data: xds
    
                                    
                                              },
                                              {
                                                  label: 'YYY',
                                                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.8)',
                                                  borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                                                  borderWidth: 1,
                                                  hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)',
                                                  hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                                                  data: yds
                                              }
                                          ]
                                      },
                                      isLoading: false
                                  });
            });
        }
    
        render() {
            
            const {isLoading} = this.state;
            if (isLoading) {
                return <Box boxShadow={2} className={this.props.className} style={{ width: "750px", height: "242px" }}><coral-wait></coral-wait></Box>;
            }
            const options = {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                  display: true,
                  position:'bottom',
                  labels: {
                    fontSize: 2,
                    boxWidth: 8
                  }
                },
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:'MTTT',
                    fontSize:16
                },
                type: "bar",
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                      stacked: true,
                      scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Day',
                        fontSize: 14
                      },
                      ticks: {
                          fontSize: 12
                      }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 50000,
                            fontSize: 12
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                          display: true,
                          labelString: 'TTTTT',
                          fontSize: 14
    
                        }
                    }]
                },
                legend:{
                    display:true,
                    position:'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        fontSize: 10,
                        boxWidth: 12
                    }
                }
            };
            return (
                <div>
                <Box boxShadow={2} className={this.props.className}>
                    <Bar
                        data={this.state.data}
                        options={options}
                    />
                </Box>
         
                 <div>
                   <div>
                     <select id="dropdown" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}>
                       <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       <option value="3">3</option>
                       <option value="4">4</option>
                     </select>
                   </div>
         
                   <div>Selected value is : {this.state.selectValue}</div>
                   name={this.state.selectValue};
                 </div>
               </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default test;
```

Comment: `name` is declared in state object. It can only be accessed by using `this.state.name`. Try updating your code to `name: this.state.name`

Comment: changing  does not render the dropdown axios.get('/api/search/a', {
                params: {
                     name:this.state.name 
                }
            }